# jQuery No Toggle when element inside parent element is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have a simple search form that is toggled when a link is clicked. When I try and click on the text input field inside of the form, the toggle on the list item fires and the form is hidden again. I am sure this is due to the form being a child element of the parent element. Is there a way to only have the toggle class work on the parent element and not the children? Thanks for any help.

jQuery:

```
$('li.search').click(function(){
    $('#search-box-container').toggle("fast");
});
```

HTML:

```
<li class="search"><a href="#">SEARCH
    <ul id="search-box-container" style="display: none;">
         <li>
             <form name="catsearchform66594" method="post" action="/Default.aspx?SiteSearchID=2829&PageID={module_oid}">
                 <div class="search-box">
                     <input class="cat_textbox_small" type="text" name="CAT_Search" id="CAT_Search" />
                     <input class="cat_button" type="submit" value="Search" />
                 </div>
              </form>
        </li>
    </ul></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the class name of li but the event source would be anchor tag

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ecpj/1/)**

```
$('li.search').click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).parent().hasClass("search"))
       $('#search-box-container').toggle("fast");
});
```

You can use event.target.tagName to skip the execution.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ecpj/)**

```
$('li.search').click(function(event){
    if(event.target.tagName == "A")
       $('#search-box-container').toggle("fast");
});
```